# Sqlite in python - print after every insert

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite, execute

```
con=sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor=con.cursor()
sql=[("1", "first", "New"),("2", "second", "New"),("3", "third", "New")]
cursor.executemany("""insert into table(srnumber, order, type)
              values(?,?,?)""",sql)
for row in cursor.execute('select * from table WHERE type ="New"'):
    print(row)
```

This prints all the newly inserted records only once. I want to be able to print after every insert.

**After the first insert:**

1 first New

**After the second insert:**

1 first New

2 second New

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must insert the rows one at a time with `execute()` and not `executemany()` and after each row is inserted you must execute the `SELECT...` statement:

```
rows = [("1", "first", "New"),("2", "second", "New"),("3", "third", "New")]
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO tablename(srnumber, `order`, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE type = 'New'"
for row in rows:
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, row)
    for inserted_row in cursor.execute(sql_select):
        print(inserted_row)
```

Note that if there are already rows in the table with `type = 'New'` they will all be returned by the `SELECT...` statement.